# How to get current location's longitude and latitude in iOS 4.0/4.2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios-4.2, cllocationmanager

I've problem to obtain current location Longitude and Latitude in iOS 4.0 also tried in iOS 4.2 actually i want to draw route on my apps from current position to specific location, i tried many way in my apps but i can't get result

please reply anyone know about this.

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Did you try `CLLocationManager`?

Answer (score 16):

```
CLLocationManager *lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
lm.delegate = self;
lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
[lm startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocation *location = [lm location];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
coord.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
// or a one shot fill
coord = [location coordinate];
```

Comment: `location` will most likely be nil or out of date if you use this approach. The OP should be implementing `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` to receive updates as they come in.

Comment: That is true. If they want the best chance for accuracy, they should query the coordinates from inside that method. But this way should at least give them a good start.

Comment: Hi @BillBurgess this answer is worked for me in IOS 6 But IOS 5.1 Its not working... any alternates ... !

Comment: Probably changed in the last two years but now it should be:    `coord.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
coord.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;`

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer, it is working for me (at least).

Answer (score 5):

Download this [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html)

this example will show you current lat long

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call CLLocationManager (See [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)). - `startUpdatingLocation` and - `stopUpdatingLocation` are one of the main methods you will be using.